# How can I exclude a classname from parent's properties?

Tags: html, css

I have a class like this:

```
li {
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: fixed;

    /* and some other properties */
}
```

Now I have this element that I want to exclude those properties above on it:

```
<li class="has_not_any_property"></li>
```

Is doing that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `:not` property.A negation pseudo class

```
li :not(.has_not_any_property) {
        color: #ccc;
        font-size: 12px;
        position: fixed;
    }
```

For older browsers that do not support CSS3 you can just give the inital or inherited values using `unset`

From the documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset

> This keyword resets the property to its inherited value if it inherits
>   from its parent or to its initial value if not. In other words, it
>   behaves like the inherit keyword in the first case and like the
>   initial keyword in the second case.

```
li.has_not_any_property {
    color:unset;
    position: unset
    font-size: unset;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is correct .. but actually the most of my website's users use IE8 `:-)` .. And as you know it doesn't support CSS3 .. thanks anyway .. upvote .. for you, but I'm looking for an other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS `not` pseudo-class:

```
li:not(.has_not_any_property) {
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: Yes this is correct .. but actually the most of my website's users use IE8 `:-)` .. And as you know it doesn't support CSS3 .. thanks anyway .. upvote .. for you, but I'm looking for an other solution.

Comment: @MartinAJ Ah, that does change things. Maybe after your CSS block for the `li` element, write out a CSS block specifically for the `.has_not_any_property` class that restores the default values for color, font-size, and position. Another option is to add a different CSS class for all `li` elements that are not to be excluded and change your existing CSS to only set for that class.